# Structuremap and ASP.NET core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, structuremap

I am using ASP.NET core and I'm trying to make use of structuremap for my IoC, but I seem to be having some issues.  When I write a unit test that inits structuremap directly, everything works fine.  When  I print the configuration out to file, I can see that my setup is indeed registering everything correctly.

However, the populate seems to be giving me trouble.

I am trying to use [StructureMap.Microsoft.DependencyInjection](https://github.com/structuremap/StructureMap.Microsoft.DependencyInjection) but I get an error when I build:

> The dependency structuremap >= 4.4.0 could not be resolved.

I have StructureMap 4.4.1 installed in my project, including the project I installed the StructureMap.Microsoft.DependencyInjection library into (my Web API project).

So, I then took the files out of the project on github and loaded them into my solution, and removed the nuget package, but for some reason it is not working.

[Here is a plunker with the relevant files](https://embed.plnkr.co/huvPNAulnW7unGfeVRoT/)

Ideally, I'd rather use the nuget package to do this, but I've never encountered a dependency issue when I have the actual dependency already installed.

EDIT:  A few more details

When I write the results of `container.WhatDoIHave()` to a file, my classes are all shown correctly t0 be part of structuremap, however when I run `container.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` is when I am getting errors about things correctly defined as reported by `WhatDoIHave()`

Here is what my configure method looks like

```
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureIoC(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var container = new Container();

        container.Configure(config =>
        {
            // scan the webapi to register all the controllers
            config.Scan(scan =>
            {
                scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                scan.WithDefaultConventions();
            });

            //this is an IoC configuration in another library that 
            //   ties together a bunch of class libraries so they 
            //   don't all have to be in my web project
            IoC.BootStrapper.Configure(config, "MembershipReboot");
        });

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\users\{me}\documents\structuremapTest.txt", container.WhatDoIHave());

        container.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        //Populate the container using the service collection
        container.Populate(services);

        return container.GetInstance<IServiceProvider>();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename the "StructureMap" package to "structuremap", seems like some weird issue with NuGet casing.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

See this issue on the StructureMap.Microsoft.DependencyInjection issue tracker:

**The dependency structuremap >= 4.3.0 could not be resolved**
https://github.com/structuremap/StructureMap.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/issues/17